# Problem with $request->request->set() method in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

Im having a problem with Symfony. This has always worked for me:.

```
$customObj = $entityManager->getRepository("App\Entity\CustomEntity")->findOneBy(["id" => $request->get("_customObjId")]);

if ($customObj != null) {   
    $request->request->set("_company", $customObj);
}
```

When changing version in Symfony I am getting this error.

*`"Expected a scalar, or an array as a 2nd argument to "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\InputBag::set()\", \"App\\Entity\\CustomEntity\" given."`*

The object obviously exists in the database. I have tried to serialize / normalize it before setting it but it doesn't work either.

Someone help me? I have tried to assign the object to the request in many ways and I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just set its id and retrieve where needed?

Comment: Hi @DonCallisto. Thank you for answering so quickly. I use doctrine and its methods to create records in the database, so I must pass objects of entity type and not just the id as integer

Comment: You can retrieve the entity by its id

Comment: where/how and why do you do this? Looks like you're trying to enrich your request in an event handler. doesn't look like this would be required by standard symfony (at least the error message suggests that), so you should name your additional framework/bundle you're using. I mean, the error message is quite explanatory, the InputBag only accepts arrays or scalars, but an object is none of those two. so it becomes a question of what the receiver of that request does, you probably can't use the currently used approach anymore unless you change Request or InputBag.

Comment: Hi @Jakumi.  I asked to know if was any alternative to enrich the request as I was doing until now. I do not contemplate modifying anything related to Request or InputBag, so for now I will use another variable to store all the data instead of request. Thanks!

Comment: ah, in that case, you could use the parameterbag `$request->attributes->set(...)` it's very similar to the old $request->request ;o)